# error on Tkinter askopenfilename method

Tags: python, tkinter

```
self.file_opt=options={}
options['defaultextension']='.txt'
options['filetypes']=[('text files','.txt')]
options=['initialdir']=['home/var/www/']
options=['initialfile']='sampl1.py'
options['parent']=root
options['title']='This is a title'
```

In the above code i get error on following..

```
options=['initialdir']=['home/var/www/']
options=['initialfile']='sampl1.py'
```

syntax error- Can't assign to literal

Don't know why it is happening.. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assigned to a literal (`['x']` is a list literal):

```
>>> ['x'] = [1]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to literal
```

Remove `=` in the following lines:

```
options=['initialdir']=['home/var/www/']
options=['initialfile']='sampl1.py'
#      ^
```